# Cognos 10.1.1 Query studio static prompt values

Tags: cognos

How do I create a query studio prompt on a filter to have a static set of values to choose from instead of reaching out to the database to get the options available?

I created a "Pick values from a list" filter and chose "Prompt every time the report runs" options. When the report runs, the prompt page comes up and it takes a long time to load the values for the list. Is there a way I can create a static set of values to choose from ?

I cannot use Report Studio and so the advanced options are available to me.

Comment: That `Pick values from a list` choice is going going to give you a distinct set of values in that column. It's going to run the query every time. There is really no way around that.  If you have the ability, maybe you could create a lookup table that has only those values, and in your package join to that.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I think that's what I will have to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the Condition 'Show only the following' and check the values you want in your static list, it will no longer perform a query for that prompt.